# How to JOIN several tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

On MS SQL Server i want to join some tables in one select.

Tables:

Track:

```
Segment_ID | Track_INFO
```

Segment_ID:

```
Segment_ID | Road_ID
```

Road:

```
Road_ID | Road_INFO
```

So i want to select information from Track and Road tables. I know how to join two tables:

```
    SELECT  

    Segment_ID = T1.Segment_ID,
    Track = T1.Track,
    --Road_ID = Segment_ID.Road_ID


FROM dbo.Track T1,dbo.Road T2
LEFT JOIN Segment_ID Segment_ID ON Segment_ID.Segment_ID = T1.Segment_ID
--LEFT JOIN Road Road_ID ON Road.Road_ID = Segment_ID.Road_ID
```

But how to make JOIN in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * 
from Track inner join Segment_ID on Track.Segment_ID = Segment_ID.Segment_ID
 inner join Road on Segment_ID.Road_ID = Road.Road_ID
```

also you can change "inner join"s to "left join"s depending on the behaviour you want

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT Track.Track_INFO, Road.Road_INFO
FROM Track 
INNER JOIN Segment_ID ON Segment_ID.Segment_ID = Track.Segment_ID
INNER JOIN Road ON Segment_ID.Road_ID = Road.RodaID
```

And also, maybe you need LEFT join if you have Null marks...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT  t.*, r.* 
FROM track t 
INNER JOIN segment s ON t.Segment_ID = s.Segment_ID 
INNER JOIN road r ON s.Road_ID = s.Road_ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to avoid table joining as below which is obsolete now.

```
FROM Table1 T1, Table2 T2
WHERE T1.id = T2.id
```

Better way of joining table is using `INNER JOIN` (or `JOIN`), `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN` etc *depending on your requirement* like;

```
SELECT * --Or you can get required list of columns using table aliases (t,s,r)
FROM dbo.Track t JOIN dbo.Segment_ID s ON t.Segment_ID = s.Segment_ID
         JOIN dbo.Road r ON s.Road_ID = r.Road_ID
```

Here are some good [**graphical examples**](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/) about *JOINS* and what results they bring